# is there a way to change the behavior of notepad++ auto-indent?

Tags: notepad++

I have a problem with notepad++ auto-indent. let's assume the `¬` is my cursor.

if the text is like this:

```
my text
    my text¬
```

and press [enter] it turns to this:

```
my text
    mytext
    ¬
```

this is perfectly fine. but when the text is like this:

```
my text
    my text
¬
```

and i press [enter], it goes like:

```
my text
    my text

    ¬
```

note that the cursor advances itself. this behavior doesn't work for me. i would like it to just keep the actual indentation instead of "playing smart". the correct behavior (to me) would be:

```
my text
    my text

¬
```

anyone could help do that? is there a file that i could edit or a plugin for that? i don't actually want to disable the auto-indent, just change this one thing. thanks (:

Comment: There's a plugin for Notepad++ that does better smart indentation, though it's not perfect (as shown by one of my own questions).

Comment: in b4 kneejerk move-to-superuser vote... aww, too late. *Edit:* really, second voter? Programmers.SE?

Comment: @JAB: I've been using vanilla Notepad++ for years... it's really about time I try some plugins.

Comment: the faq says i can ask about: "software tools commonly used by programmers". apparently 3 people didn't read it :(

Comment: @BoltClock: Even "vanilla" NPP comes with several plugins out-of-the-box (so to speak).

Comment: @JAB can you post the link for the plugin or the question?

Comment: @JAB: Yeah I totally forgot those.

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: Hence my mean "in b4 ..." comment.

Comment: @hugo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824035/tweaking-nppautoindent-or-is-there-a-good-customizable-alternative

Comment: @JAB: If that plugin offers the functionality he needs, turn the link into an answer ;)

Comment: @Jab this plugin with the "previous line" option and "ignoring language" apparently solves my problem completely! post it so i can choose as the answer. and thank you so much (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppAutoIndent/

Glad it solved your problem.